# Data recovery seems impossible after kernel upgrade. MDADM (Raid1) LVM2

Tags: lvm, mdadm, disaster-recovery, data-recovery, sles

I opened a question about rebuilding a bad partition [My Problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/675537/disaster-recovery-mdadm-lvm2-some-advance-but-stuck-on-final-mount) that din't take me anywhere.

Bad news is the company trying to rescue the data says it's finding huge inconsistencies they can see some structures, but then files do not seem to be what they get, like a index.html file having hexadecimal GIF headers.

They are working on the images dded from the remote box, they have downloaded both 2TB disks in the raid, I'm afraid the raid was synchronized with a mdad --create after the disaster.

I'm hoping someone can point me to a way of restoring the files of the disks in the situation this data recovery company can't recover the data propperly. Apparently their signature search process is very slow with the size of the disks, and we'll not be getting any news until a copple of days.

Could anyone help me find a way to recover the files, a company that can give results, or an engineer that could work on the system?

Thanks for any help, we are desperate.

---------EDIT------------

Good news, the data-recovery company has found a way of recovering the data after some tech exchange, we have a list of files, and apparently integrity is high. We'll be getting the data in a couple of days. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: This is why things like NetBackup exist.

Comment: Yeah, I know we've taken measures to ensure that won't happen again, our problem tho, is what happened and how could we survive this.

Comment: downgrade or build another machine using the same version of the kernel/OS you had. then force mdadm to discover the LVM partition. Then you can use the same mount commands from the old server to mount your file system. at that point copy all your data to a another place, NFS maybe?

Comment: Another thing you could do is mount a single drive in a desktop pc and boot a SLES recovery disk then mount the LVM and send the files to another storage repo. Raid1 mirrors are nothing more than single disks that share a copy of the data. LVM/mdadm or conventional use. the only thing I have ran into is chipset drivers that get changed and cause the drive index to be shifted. this will cause the data to be ureadable until the correct driver is restored.

Comment: Hi Random-IT! I've been talking to the data-recovery company and we'll get the copied drives once they finish their recovery process, the idea of booting with a SLES recovery disk has been on my mind for a week now. I can't do it until I get the disks here tho. The problem seems to be that the raid partition filesystem is undetectable (the first partition (boot) without LVM is working fine and hasn't lost any data. The volume group and logical volumes do mount but their filesystem is not recognizable.

Comment: If you know the kernel version you can limit the file system formats. Most MDA LVM (use for software raid) can only be opened using the same kernel and version of the MDA software. This is not always true as with Debian 5 and 7 being able to share LVMs without issue.